# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression webpack svelte

Tags: javascript, webpack, svelte

When I try to import Gun into a svelte component using `var Gun = require("gun/gun")`, all I get is this error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/gun/gun.js 5:16-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./src/Header.svelte 196:11-29
 @ ./src/App.svelte 16:0-37 23:14-20 125:41-47
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-31 5:16-19
```

The webpack docs say that this is due to my request containing expressions, but this doesn't seem like the case.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196

Comment: Please, provide reproduction instructions.

Comment: 1. Create webpack svelte project with `npx degit sveltejs/template-webpack svelte-app` 2. download Gun 3. import gun into svelte component

Answer (score 0):

For importing the gun in svelte js file try this code below

```
import GUN from 'gun';
```

This will work